# Ler XML com Ajax, JavaScript, DOM

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom

Como é possível realizar a leitura deste XML utilizando o Ajax, tentei de diversas formas, mas até o momento infelizmente não consegui obter sucesso, o objetivo é pegar o número do inum (810265006252830) que será utilizando na concatenação com outra url no projeto que estou desenvolvendo.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<results>
<result inum="810265006252830">
<field name="startedat">2020-03-18T08:00:58.796</field>
<field name="duration">37</field>
<field name="agents">9283</field>
<field name="otherparties">1633425177</field>
<field name="services">7170</field>
<field name="skills">0200</field>
<field name="switchcallid">00001101551584529176</field>
<field name="udfs"/>
</result>
</results>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Test 1</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='main.css'>
</head>
<body>

<h2>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>
 
<script>
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         myFunction(this);
     }
  };  
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://devxavier.000webhostapp.com/results.xml", true);
  xhttp.send();

    function myFunction(xml) {
      var x, xmlDoc, txt;
      xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
      txt = "";
      x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('result');    
      txt += x.item(0).attributes[0].nodeValue;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "inum: " + txt; }
      </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Caro Célio, isso esta incorreto `txt += x[i].getElementsByTagName('inum');`, isso pega uma LISTA de elementos e **não** o conteudo do elemento, para pegar o conteudo terá que pegar elemento a elemento e usar `.text`

Comment: Guilherme, ficaria mais ou menos assim:                                                                        function myFunction(xml) {
      var x, xmlDoc, txt;
      xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
      x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('result');
      var txt = x[0].getAttribute('inum');
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
      alert(txt.txt); 
  }

Comment: Infelizmente ainda eu não consegui pegar o valor do inum, não apresenta nenhum erro no console.

Comment: Caro Célio não é `txt.txt` o certo é `.text`, mas uma coisa notei, vc usou inum, que é um atributo, getElementsByTagName é para pegar pelo nome do elemento e não pelo atributo, vai retornar uma lista, o certo seria `getElementsByTagName('result');` como no exemplo da documentação: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName#Example, basta trocar document pelo contexto do xml.responseXML

Comment: @Guilherme Nascimento consegui pegar o valor do inum mas inserindo este xml em um servidor, inclusive o código do post foi atualizado com a correção. Agora estou trabalhando em um outro cenário que é pegar o xml no localhost. Muito obrigado pela força man!!!

Comment: Por nada, desejo sucesso pra ti Célio!